# Index: Repeat first-level item on new column/page?

Tags: page-breaking, indexing

In my family history book, I'm using a two-level index.  First level is surname, and second level is given name.  Index items are defined such as the following:

```
\index{Doe!John}
```

Often a first-level will contain many second-level items (one surname, many given names).  When the second-level overflows to a new column or page, I would like to repeat the first-level item.  Is this possible?

Here is an example of the default behavior:

Column 1:

```
Doe
    John, 3, 6, 9
    Melvin, 6, 14, 18
    Sally, 24, 32
```

Column 2:

```
    Timothy, 11, 15, 27
    Victor, 5
Smith
    Gary, 7, 18
```

Here is what I would like to see:

Column 1:

```
Doe
    John, 3, 6, 9
    Melvin, 6, 14, 18
    Sally, 24, 32
```

Column 2:

```
Doe (continued)
    Timothy, 11, 15, 27
    Victor, 5
Smith
    Gary, 7, 18
```

Note the "Doe (continued)" at the start of column one.  This combines re-showing the level-one name, and appending text to it.

Is this possible?

Edit: Here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=3in]{geometry}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some text.

\index{Jones!Alvin}
\index{Jones!Billy}
\index{Jones!Carter}
\index{Jones!Dennis}

\index{Smith!Alex}
\index{Smith!Brian}
\index{Smith!Carrie}
\index{Smith!Dewey}
\index{Smith!Eric}
\index{Smith!Frank}
\index{Smith!Gary}
\index{Smith!Huey}
\index{Smith!Irma}
\index{Smith!Joey}
\index{Smith!Kevin}
\index{Smith!Louie}
\index{Smith!Martin}
\index{Smith!Ned}
\index{Smith!Opal}
\index{Smith!Paul}
\index{Smith!Quincey}
\index{Smith!Rosie}
\index{Smith!Steven}
\index{Smith!Thomas}

\index{White!Alice}
\index{White!Barney}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I run it through the following:

```
pdflatex MWE.tex
makeindex MWE.idx
pdflatex MWE.tex
```

This produces a PDF where the index has "Smith" names across columns one and two on page one, and in column one on page two.  I'd like to have page one, column two and page two, column one both begin with "Smith (continued)", but have yet to find any way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

The [`repeatindex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/repeatindex) package (from 2001) offers this functionality (note that it requires a special `.ind` format which may be created using the accompanying style file  `repeatindex.ist`). However, the package README lists some known problems:

> - When an item is repeated a small vertical space is included two items later
> - If the last item is a subitem and the only entry on the last page of the index the repeation is omitted

Both problems are present in your modified example. A third problem is that `repeatindex` doesn't seem to cope with index items that exclusively point to subitems (i.e., don't feature at least one self-contained entry), so I had to to add `\item{Jones}`, `\item{Smith}`, and `\item{White}` to your example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=3in]{geometry}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{repeatindex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
item_0 "\n  \\item ["
delim_0 "], "
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\index{Jones}
\index{Jones!Alvin}
\index{Jones!Billy}
\index{Jones!Carter}
\index{Jones!Dennis}

\index{Smith}
\index{Smith!Alex}
\index{Smith!Brian}
\index{Smith!Carrie}
\index{Smith!Dewey}
\index{Smith!Eric}
\index{Smith!Frank}
\index{Smith!Gary}
\index{Smith!Huey}
\index{Smith!Irma}
\index{Smith!Joey}
\index{Smith!Kevin}
\index{Smith!Louie}
\index{Smith!Martin}
\index{Smith!Ned}
\index{Smith!Opal}
\index{Smith!Paul}
\index{Smith!Quincey}
\index{Smith!Rosie}
\index{Smith!Steven}
\index{Smith!Thomas}

\index{White}
\index{White!Alice}
\index{White!Barney}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This gets me very close to what I'm looking for, especially, since I can \renewcommand on \entryprefix and \entrypostfix. I'll have to see if I can figure out how to remove the page numbers from the top-level items, however.

Comment: @ChristopherFritz - did you work out how to remove the page numbers from the top-level items?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no page numbers on a top-level item, the delimiter can be written by adding `item_x1` to the index style.  Also adding curly braces to protect against square brackets in item names, the style comes to

```
item_0 "\n  \\item [{"
delim_0 "}], "
item_x1 "}]\n    \\subitem "
```