# Repeating top-level index entries on the next column (done right)

Tags: page-breaking, indexing, afterpage

Yes, I want exactly the same thing as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98559/index-repeat-first-level-item-on-new-column-page). However, I'm trying to get rid of the following three issues with [`repeatindex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/repeatindex)/[`afterpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage):

1. `afterpage` causes **loathsome** small vertical space after the second entry in the column.
2. `repeatindex` does not work if index entries contain commands.
3. My solution for the second issue works incorrectly with entries that have only subentries.

I don't know what really causes the first issue, but it's definitely `afterpage`. Its doc says that it does not work in two-column mode, so it kinda justifies this, but anyway... I've tried doing something like

```
\gdef\ResetAfterFix{\gdef\AfterFix{\ResetAfterFix}}
\ResetAfterFix
% ...
\newcommand{\metaitem}[2]{\item #1 #2\relax\AfterFix}
```

and then putting `\gdef\AfterFix{\vskip-1234pt\ResetAfterFix}` into what `afterpage` should output, but it seems that `afterpage` expands and lays out its 'aftertext' *after* the first couple of lines on the second page, so the `\AfterFix` is applied at the wrong place.

`repeatindex` appears to have a solution for this expansion issue (see `\@entry` and `\@@entry`) but I failed to adapt it to my case.

I don't really understand how `afterpage` works by delaying the output, but I also suspect its `\baselineskip` 'faking' in `\addboxcontents` as the cause of the issue.

---

I've circumvented the second issue by ditching the empty continuation checks from `repeatindex` which were expanding the contents:

```
% Reset afterpage contents
\long\def\ResetAfterPage#1{%
    \gdef\AP@{{#1\par}}%
    \global\output{%
        \the\AP@output
        \ifnum\outputpenalty>-\@Mi
            \global\output\expandafter{\the\AP@output}%
            \aftergroup\AP@@
        \fi
    }%
}

% This will be put at the top of the page
\gdef\index@cont{}

% Continuation label
\newcommand{\indexcont}{(\textit{cont.})}

% These commands are output by index-preparing program
\newcommand{\metaitem}[2]{%
    \item #1 #2
    \gdef\index@cont{#1\relax\ \indexcont}% Store what will be repeated
    \ResetAfterPage{}% And prevent repeating it without any following \subitems
}
\newcommand{\metasubitem}[2]{%
    \subitem #1 #2
    \ResetAfterPage{\index@cont}%
}
\newcommand{\metasubsubitem}[2]{
    \subsubitem #1 #2
    \ResetAfterPage{\index@cont}%
}
```

---

The third issue has to do with the entries like

```
foo
   bar, 12
   baz, 42
```

which result into

```
foo (cont.)
foo
   bar, 12
   baz, 42
```

if this happens at the top of the column. I believe it has to do something with `afterpage` again: it appears to be tricked by LaTeX into thinking that `foo` was left behind, but then LaTeX puts it onto the next page. However, I doubt this is a correct explanation as this happens regardless of the entry length or something, but the page numbers after the item *do matter*.

I've circumvented this by making the index preparer to output `\ResetAfterPage{}` after *the first subitem* of items without pages , but this is hardly an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `afterpage` to work for me. To solve this problem I wound up using a combination of hand work and software.

Let's suppose I have an item ITEM with subitem SUB6 and the bottom of one column and SUB7 at the top of the next.  I need to insert a continuation between them.

1. In a file containing a list of continuations, I add an index entry in the position where I want the continuation.  For example,

   ```
   \index{ITEM!SUB61}
   ```
2. These entries get run through a program that takes the *last* item in the list and replaces the "actual" text with the continuation and adds the page number CCC.  For example,

   ```
   \index{ITEM!SUB61}
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   \indexentry {ITEM!SUB61@z{\par\penalty-9000 \item ITEM (continued)}}{CCC}
   ```

   And

   ```
   \index{ITE}
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   \indexentry {ITE@z{\par\penalty-9000}}{CCC}
   ```

   And

   ```
   \index{ITEM!SUB12!SUBSUB97}
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   \indexentry {ITEM!SUB12+SUBSUB97@z{\par\penalty-9000\item ITEM (continued) \subitem SUB12 (continued)}}{CCC}
   ```

   The `\indexentry` lines get added to the document's `idx` file.
3. Run `makeindex` with the `-s wide.ist` option, which adds this style option:

   ```
   line_max 2000
   ```
4. Postprocess the resulting `.ind` file to find all lines with page CCC, strip off the page and the initial control sequence, and include just what's between the matching braces `z{...}`.

The process is tedious because every time a new continuation is added to the list, the positions of all subsequent items change.  But for a two-column, 27-page index I was able to get it all done in less than an hour.  And the results are perfect.