# Formatting index with "main entry (continued)" when columns start with sub-entries

Tags: xetex, indexing

Is there a package which can generate an index like the following, where (for example) the "fingering" entry had several sub-entries on the previous page but continues at the top of the page shown below, and similarly the "flow headings" main entry started at the end of the first column on the page and continues onto the second column?

[image]

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Comment: I had to do this by hand. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651495/5847.