# LaTeX: Insert tokens or vbox at the top of the next new column or page?

Tags: two-column, afterpage, output-routine

I'd like to be able to add material to the top of a new column or page.  I want to insert this material into the body causing the next column to reflow. (The problem I'm trying to solve is [continuing an index entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140917/) in a two-column index.  The existing solution recommends hacking `\afterpage`, but ordinary vanilla `\afterpage` is creating a new *page* after each column. And there are other issues.)

I'm hoping there may be a hook in LaTeX's `\output` routine that would allow me to add something to the vertical list that will be typeset after the current page or column is shipped out.  The material I want to add is in a tokens register, but I imagine I'll have to put it into a vbox.  That will be OK.  But I have no idea if there are suitable hooks in LaTeX's output routine or really where to begin here.

Does anybody know how I can hook into the `\output` routine so I can potentially add items to the vertical list that will appear on the *next* column or page?

Comment: do you want to insert it in an available space (like a page head, but for columns) or do you want to insert it in to the body causing the next column to reflow? The latter is a lot more fragile witness the many "features" of `\afterpage`.

Comment: Edited to add: I want to insert it into the body, causing the next column to reflow.

Comment: FYI, in case anybody looking for index help finds this question: I wound up writing coded to massage the `.idx` and `.ind` files in a way that I can (relatively) easily add the "continued" entries by hand.