# Repeat subentry imakidx index on new pages

Tags: koma-script, book-design, scrbook, imakeidx

I'm using `imakeidx` to create long indexes that span several pages. In case the (sub)subentries extend to new pages, I would like the main entry (plus subentry) to be repeated at the top of the page. So in the following MWE, I would like page three to begin again with "Testing, testing, one, two, three, four", then "Two" hanging under that, and only then the rest of the subentries. How do I make this happen?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=156mm:235mm, BCOR=12mm, headings=optiontotocandhead, headings=openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options= -s index_style2.ist, intoc,name=A,title=\mbox{Appendix A},columns=1]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Dotfill}{\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\chapter{The First Chapter} 
\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!Z}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!Z}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!Z} \index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!Z}

\backmatter
\indexprologue{\small Description of Appendix A goes here.}

\printindex[A]

\end{document}
```

With the index_styel2.ist:

```
item_0 "\n \\item \\small "

delim_0 " \\Dotfill "
delim_1 " \\Dotfill "
delim_2 " \\Dotfill "
```

I've found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98559/index-repeat-first-level-item-on-new-column-page) question, but when I try to implement what I find there as a solution, it yields errors in a `.ind` output file, and mysteriously 'it' and 'it...' appear above the new page, instead of the index entries. That's what happens when using the following in Overleaf (with same `.ist` file):

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=156mm:235mm, BCOR=12mm, headings=optiontotocandhead, headings=openany]{scrbook}


\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options= -s index_style2.ist, intoc,name=A,title=\mbox{Appendix A},columns=1]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Dotfill}{\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{repeatindex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
item_0 "\n  \\item ["
delim_0 "], "
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\chapter{The First Chapter} 
\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!Z}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!Z}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!Z} \index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!Z}

\backmatter
\indexprologue{\small Description of Appendix A goes here.}

\printindex[A]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please specify your problem with the solution to your linked question.

Comment: @dexteritas Thank you; I've elaborated my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the errors, that mentioned `it...` is coming from italic shape. As per my ide, I see the following error

[image]

it means that `\mathit` is being used and leads to error because it requires math mode.

Diving into [`repeatindex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/repeatindex) source code more deeply, you can find out that

```
\renewcommand{\subsubitem}{%
    \orig@subsubitem
    \expandafter\hhafterpage\expandafter{\expandafter\par\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\itshape\@@entry\dots}}%
    \xdef\@@entry{\@entry}%
  }
```

is responsible for duplicating top level index item.

The package was created in 2001 and since then many things changed in LaTeX sources, including `\itshape`. If you run `\show\itshape` you will see

```
> \itshape=\protected macro:
->\not@math@alphabet \itshape \mathit \fontshape \itdefault \selectfont .
l.75 \show\itshape
```

so that it is defined to be a protected macro, basically if you look up LaTeX sources in `base/ltfssaxes.dtx‎`, you will find the definition

```
\protected\def\itshape
     {\not@math@alphabet\itshape\mathit
      \fontshape\itdefault\selectfont}%
```

So that you have two options:

1. Modify `repeatindex` package code and add `\protect` before `\itshape` either directly or via `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd`
2. Change `\itshape` itself inside your preamble by adding `\protect` in its definition or declaring the command as robust at the first place.

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \protected\def\itshape
        {\protect\not@math@alphabet\itshape\mathit
         \fontshape\itdefault\selectfont}%
   \makeatother
   ```

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \DeclareRobustCommand\itshape
           {\not@math@alphabet\itshape\mathit
            \fontshape\itdefault\selectfont}
   \makeatother
   ```

   any of the code pieces will do the job.

Having said, it worth mentioning that `repeatindex` requires a special syntax to work correctly

> you have to produce
> the .ind file in a special format in which the entries of the `\item`
> are enclosed in `[...]` (example:   `\item [Main Item A], 1, 3, 6`  ).

As I can see, you're trying to do so via

```
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
item_0 "\n  \\item ["
delim_0 "], "
\end{filecontents}
```

but since you've specified `index_style2.ist` as your style file, the code above has no effect at all. You'd rather need to modify the `index_style2.ist` itself including those changes.

## TL;DR

`repeatindex` hasn't been updating since 2001 and some fundamental commands has been changed, namely `\itshape`. Add the following code right before `\printindex[A]` to get it fixed

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\itshape
        {\not@math@alphabet\itshape\mathit
         \fontshape\itdefault\selectfont}
\makeatother
```

Also make some changes to your `index_style2.ist` to make the package work correctly:

```
item_0 "\n \\small\\item ["
item_x1 "]\n    \\subitem "

delim_0 "] \\Dotfill "
delim_1 " \\Dotfill "
delim_2 " \\Dotfill "
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=156mm:235mm, BCOR=12mm, headings=optiontotocandhead, headings=openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options= -s index_style2.ist, intoc,name=A,title=\mbox{Appendix A},columns=1]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Dotfill}{\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{repeatindex}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\chapter{The First Chapter} 
\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!1@One!Z}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!2@Two!Z}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!3@Three!Z} \index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!A}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!B}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!C}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!D}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!E}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!F}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!G}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!H}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!I}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!J}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!K}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!L}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!M}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!N}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!O}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!P}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!Q}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!R}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!S}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!T}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!U}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!V}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!X}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!Y}\index[A]{Testing, testing, one, two, three, four!4@Four!Z}

\backmatter
\indexprologue{\small Description of Appendix A goes here.}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\itshape
        {\not@math@alphabet\itshape\mathit
         \fontshape\itdefault\selectfont}
\makeatother
\printindex[A]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @antshar - I've posted a follow-up question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656920/making-repeatindex-play-nicely-with-imakeidx-and-glossaries