# Making repeatindex play nicely with imakeidx and glossaries

Tags: koma-script, glossaries, book-design, imakeidx

This is a follow-up question to [my earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656259/repeat-subentry-imakidx-index-on-new-pages/656675#656675). My goal is to get `repeatindex` to work the way it was designed: to repeat the main index item at the top of every new page. The answer given to my earlier question worked for the simplified MWE I originally gave. However, when I tried implementing the solution in the actual project I'm working on, the `glossaries` package and/or some simple custom commands seem to be creating mutliple LaTeX errors. The fault are recreated in this new MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=156mm:235mm, BCOR=12mm, headings=optiontotocandhead, headings=openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options= -s index_style2.ist, intoc,name=A,title=\mbox{Appendix A},columns=1]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Dotfill}{\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{repeatindex}

\newcommand{\testing}{\Gls{test}, \emph{testing}, one, two, three, three, four (\emph{1, 2, 3, 4})}

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{test}
    {
        name=test,
        description={test},
        text=testing,
        sort=test
    }

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\chapter{The First Chapter}


\index[A]{\testing!1@One!A}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!B}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!C}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!D}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!E}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!F}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!G}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!H}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!I}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!J}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!K}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!L}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!M}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!N}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!O}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!P}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!Q}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!R}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!S}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!T}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!U}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!V}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!X}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!Y}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!Z}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!A}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!B}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!C}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!D}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!E}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!F}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!G}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!H}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!I}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!J}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!K}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!L}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!M}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!N}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!O}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!P}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!Q}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!R}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!S}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!T}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!U}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!V}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!X}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!Y}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!Z}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!A}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!B}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!C}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!D}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!E}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!F}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!G}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!H}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!I}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!J}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!K}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!L}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!M}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!N}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!O}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!P}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!Q}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!R}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!S}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!T}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!U}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!V}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!X}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!Y}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!Z} \index[A]{\testing!4@Four!A}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!B}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!C}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!D}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!E}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!F}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!G}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!H}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!I}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!J}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!K}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!L}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!M}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!N}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!O}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!P}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!Q}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!R}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!S}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!T}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!U}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!V}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!X}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!Y}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!Z}

\backmatter
\indexprologue{\small Description of Appendix A goes here.}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\itshape
        {\not@math@alphabet\itshape\mathit
         \fontshape\itdefault\selectfont}
\makeatother
\printindex[A]

\end{document}
```

The `index_style2.ist` file contains:

```
item_0 "\n \\small\\item ["
item_x1 "]\n    \\subitem "

delim_0 "] \\Dotfill "
delim_1 " \\Dotfill "
delim_2 " \\Dotfill "
```

Why do many LaTeX errors now ensue and how to prevent them?

Comment: The problem is with `repeatindex` itself. If you look closer to the source code, you'll find out that it fully expands the item, so even a simple `\emph` causes an error. The package not only outdated, but also not tested enough as its author mentions.

Comment: In order to encourage more people into the problem, you might need to ask a more general question, without referencing your previous question so that people won't need to deep into details. The index is basically a list like `itemize` or `enumerate`, so your goal is to find out whether a page break occurs between subitems and if so, repeat the item. Therefore the general question would be "detect page break between items in a list".

Comment: Thank you. I have now abandoned `repeatindex` and posted a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657027/detect-page-break-between-items-in-a-list