# Detect page break between items in a list

Tags: lists, page-breaking, imakeidx

My  goal is to find out whether a page break occurs between subsubitems and if so, repeat the item and subitem.  Specifically, I’m trying to get the main etry and subentry of one of my `makeindx` indexes to be repeated at the top of each new even page in the book I am publishing. I have tried using the `repeatindex`-package that was designed for this, but it is out of date and by now yields too many issues.

My three-part question is:

1. How to detect where a page break appears between the subentries, or
   the subsubentries in the index;
2. Once detected, how to repeat at the top of the new page the main entry and the subentry, or  in case the page break occurs between subentries, rather than between subsubentries, to repeat just the main entry;
3. How to have the option to do this only for the even pages, and only in one of several imakeidx indexes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=156mm:235mm, BCOR=12mm, headings=optiontotocandhead, headings=openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options= -s index_style2.ist, intoc,name=A,title=\mbox{Appendix A},columns=1]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Dotfill}{\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\testing}{Testing, \emph{testing}, one, two, three, three, four (\emph{1, 2, 3, 4})}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\chapter{The First Chapter}

I could place some placeholder text here, but you get the idea.

\index[A]{\testing!1@One!A}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!B}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!C}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!D}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!E}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!F}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!G}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!H}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!I}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!J}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!K}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!L}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!M}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!N}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!O}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!P}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!Q}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!R}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!S}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!T}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!U}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!V}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!X}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!Y}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!Z}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!A}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!B}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!C}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!D}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!E}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!F}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!G}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!H}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!I}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!J}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!K}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!L}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!M}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!N}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!O}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!P}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!Q}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!R}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!S}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!T}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!U}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!V}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!X}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!Y}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!Z}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!A}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!B}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!C}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!D}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!E}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!F}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!G}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!H}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!I}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!J}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!K}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!L}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!M}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!N}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!O}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!P}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!Q}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!R}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!S}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!T}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!U}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!V}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!X}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!Y}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!Z} \index[A]{\testing!4@Four!A}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!B}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!C}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!D}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!E}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!F}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!G}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!H}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!I}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!J}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!K}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!L}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!M}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!N}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!O}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!P}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!Q}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!R}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!S}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!T}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!U}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!V}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!X}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!Y}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!Z}

\backmatter
\indexprologue{\small Description of Appendix A goes here. And I'm making this description slightly longer, so that the page break between pages three and four actually occurs in the middle of several subsubentries.}
\printindex[A]

\end{document}
```

The `index_style2.ist`-file contains:

```
delim_0 "] \\Dotfill "
delim_1 " \\Dotfill "
delim_2 " \\Dotfill "
```

What I am looking for, is for a page 4 that looks like this: [image: example list page break question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not (easily?) possible to determine the break points from the tex source's "point of view". This has something to do with the asynchronous output routine of TeX, where it "reads" text chunk-wise (usually paragraphs) and then "decides" which parts of the chunk are to be placed on what page. With other words, you can't hook into the definitions of your (sub)subentry-macros to "ask" whether they will be placed on or after a page break, because by the time TeX parses and fully expands these macros, it doesn't know yet, where the fully expanded content of those macros will be placed.

However, there are ways to hook into the page breaks itself.

One way to do that would be to use the [atbegshi](https://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) package and the `\AtBeginShipout{\ifodd\thepage\testing\fi}` macro right before `\printindex[A]`.

An alternative way without using an external package is via the pagestyle, the thing that draws page headers and page footers.

To do that, we create a new pagestyle named `index`. Pagestyles are defined with the `ps@`-prefix, so we need `\makeatletter`. Since we only want to change the head of even pages, we load whatever the document class provides as default pagestyle, so that odd pages and all page footers stay the way they were. After that we only re-define the macro that prints the head on even pages. Therein, we place the contents of the `\testing`-macro at the height of the first line. The full definition of our new pagestyle is:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@index{%
  %% load original page style:
  \ps@headings
  %% redefine the style of head on even pages:
  \renewcommand*{\@evenhead}{%
    %% this part is from the original definition
    %% (taken from scrbook.cls)
    \set@tempdima@hw\hss\hb@xt@ \@tempdima{\vtop{%
        \hb@xt@ \@tempdima{{\headfont\strut\leftmark\hfil}}%
        \if@hsl \vskip 1.5\p@ \hrule \fi
        %% this is the new part.
        %% go back to the left egde of the type area:
        \par
        %% go down to the first line of the type area:
        \vskip\dimexpr\headsep+\dp\strutbox\relax
        %% print the \testing macro without stretching the header itself:
        \smash{\rlap{\hb@xt@\hsize{\testing\hss}}}%
      }% /vbox
    }% /hbox
  }% /@evenhead
}
\makeatother
```

For the printed index, we need to switch to the new pagestyle. This is done with the `\pagestyle{}` macro, which gets the name of the new style (sans the `ps@`-prefix) as argument.

```
\pagestyle{index}
```

Finally, we need to make room for the repeating line. We do this by extending the `\topskip` value, the height of the first line on the type area of a page, by the line height of the main text font:

```
\advance\topskip\baselineskip
```

This has a few drawbacks: for one, the index on each page starts a line lower than your other text, although the repeating line is only added on even pages. I find it typographically more pleasing if the main body of the index (i.e., the entries without the "head line") is well-adjusted to start at the same height.

Second, if your repeating text gets more complicated, you may need to adjust the values at different points, once in the definition of `\@evenhead`, and a second time in the `\advance\topskip` line.

The full code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=156mm:235mm, BCOR=12mm, headings=optiontotocandhead, headings=openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options= -s index_style2.ist, intoc,name=A,title=\mbox{Appendix A},columns=1]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Dotfill}{\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\testing}{Testing, \emph{testing}, one, two, three, three, four (\emph{1, 2, 3, 4})}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@index{%
  \ps@headings
  \let\old@evenhead\@evenhead%
  \renewcommand*{\@evenhead}{%
    \set@tempdima@hw\hss\hb@xt@ \@tempdima{\vtop{%
        \hb@xt@ \@tempdima{{\headfont\strut\leftmark\hfil}}%
        \if@hsl \vskip 1.5\p@ \hrule \fi
        \par
        \vskip\dimexpr\headsep+\dp\strutbox\relax
        \smash{\rlap{\hb@xt@\hsize{\testing\hss}}}%
      }% /vbox
    }% /hbox
  }% /@evenhead
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\chapter{The First Chapter}

I could place some placeholder text here, but you get the idea.

\index[A]{\testing!1@One!A}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!B}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!C}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!D}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!E}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!F}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!G}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!H}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!I}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!J}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!K}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!L}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!M}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!N}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!O}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!P}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!Q}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!R}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!S}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!T}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!U}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!V}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!X}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!Y}\index[A]{\testing!1@One!Z}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!A}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!B}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!C}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!D}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!E}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!F}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!G}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!H}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!I}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!J}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!K}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!L}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!M}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!N}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!O}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!P}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!Q}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!R}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!S}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!T}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!U}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!V}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!X}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!Y}\index[A]{\testing!2@Two!Z}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!A}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!B}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!C}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!D}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!E}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!F}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!G}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!H}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!I}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!J}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!K}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!L}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!M}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!N}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!O}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!P}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!Q}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!R}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!S}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!T}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!U}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!V}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!X}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!Y}\index[A]{\testing!3@Three!Z} \index[A]{\testing!4@Four!A}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!B}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!C}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!D}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!E}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!F}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!G}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!H}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!I}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!J}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!K}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!L}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!M}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!N}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!O}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!P}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!Q}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!R}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!S}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!T}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!U}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!V}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!X}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!Y}\index[A]{\testing!4@Four!Z}

\backmatter
\pagestyle{index}
\advance\topskip\baselineskip
\indexprologue{\small Description of Appendix A goes here. And I'm making this description slightly longer, so that the page break between pages three and four actually occurs in the middle of several subsubentries.}
\printindex[A]

\end{document}
```

which results in this output:

[image: output with repeating line on every even page]

Comment: I'll attempt to implement this solution, but expect to run into a problem: what I am looking to be repeated at the top of even pages is the main index item AND the subentry. As an example, I have given the same main entry as a static text, as per the `\testing`-macro. In the actual book there will be different index items, of which the subentries will spill over to the next pages. I'm looking to repeat both the main entry, and the subentry, on each new even page, before the list of subsubentries continues. Is there a way amend your answer to get to this result?

Comment: This is not a simple addition. In order to do that, you'd need to alter the output of makeindex in a way that each item is collectible, similar to what `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` do. This should be doable. The more crucial problem is to catch those cases where the next higher-level item is naturally just at the top of the new page. in this case you probably don't want the automatic repeating text, but because of TeX's output routine, those cases are quite difficult to catch. I have to think about that.